# datetimepicker - Set defaultTime always return 01 hours

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

as the title says, I use the datetimepicker plugin of boostrap, and I only show the time, I want to set a default time such as 09:20 but the result is 01:20, any time I put the time always comes in 01 , my code is as follows:

```
**$("#dtpHour").datetimepicker({
    locale:locale,
    format:"HH:mm",
    allowInputToggle:!0,
    showTodayButton:!0,
    showClose:!0,
    useCurrent:false,
    defaultDate: '2018-05-26T09:20:00.000Z'
});**
```

Comment: Read about [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): _If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z"._, so by setting `Z` at the end of the `defaultDate` option, you're setting a time in UTC timezone, **but you set a specific** `locale` so it add the offset of that timezone from the UTC timezone

Comment: I found the solution: `$("#dtpHour").data('DateTimePicker').date(new Date(d.setHours(20, 10, 00)));`

Comment: Yep, that should do the trick because you don't specify any timezone, so your default timezone is applied (Which is probably the same as the one in the `locale` option)